# Cannot write to temp files using wkhtmltopdf in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, temporary-files, qpainter

I'm using Terrapin to execute wkhtmltopdf from command line inside Rails.

```
Terrapin::CommandLine.path = "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
pdfCommand = Terrapin::CommandLine.new("xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf :html_source :pdf_target")
tempHTML = Tempfile.new(["pattern", ".html"])
tempHTML << html
tempPDF = Tempfile.new(["pattern",".pdf"])
pdfCommand.run(html_source: tempHTML.path, pdf_target: tempPDF.path)
```

It runs, but returns:

```
QPainter::begin(): Returned false
Error: Unable to write to destination
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

I've made sure wkhtmltopdf has full permissions, I'm not sure if maybe Terrapin has something to do with this?

Edit: running `xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf http://www.example.com test.pdf` in console works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Terrapin to process the interpolations, they need to be in the second argument to `new`. Ie. it expects the command you're running to be separate from the string with the interpolations in it:

```rb
Terrapin::CommandLine.new("xvfb-run", "wkhtmltopdf :html_source :pdf_target")
```

If you add `Terrapin::CommandLine.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` to your script you'll see that terrapin was trying to run, literally, `xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf :html_source :pdf_target`.